# Object Mapping for Composite Columns with Hector Object Mapper

Tags: cassandra, hector

I cannot find any documentation or examples that show how to annotate a field to be a composite column. Is there anyway to do it or is it not supported?

For example,

```
@Column(name="body")
private String body;
```

That will create a column "body"

Is there a way to annotate such that it will create a composite column "body:foo"?